# pie chart on Internet Explorer 5 and Java 1.4

Tags: javascript, charts, pie-chart, java1.4, internet-explorer-5

I am developing a banking application based on very old technologies, such as `Java 1.4`, presented on `Internet Explorer 5` browser.

I have to present some data in the form of a pie chart. The problem is  that is really hard to find a solution with such old technologies.

I tried to use `Google Chart`, but we have some licence issues and, anyway, it does not work on Internet Explorer 5.

I have tried to find some javascript-based solutions using some libraries and I came up founding this so-called `donut.js` on github: https://github.com/finom/donut.js/tree/master
; also this library seems not to work properly because it does not allow to present the percentage (or any kind of written information) inside the "slice" of the pie.

On the back-end side (Java 1.4) I found a library called `JOpenChart` that seems to be a good alternative.

Can you suggest any other option, either on the front-end side and on the back-end side? Regarding the front-end side I have some proxy issues, so I need a stand-alone self-contained library.

Thanks in advance,
Francesco

Comment: With such restrictive requirements (esp since it concerns money/banking), I'd opt for a fully server driven website. So my advice would be to run a node.js server, convert the data to pie charts there and then convert the pie charts into a jpeg or other image format. The app itsself can work with basic form functionality and html4 syntax. At least try to make the server as secure as possible, since IE5 security really sucks. It's not going to be pretty though, I can't name a single library that still supports IE5.

Comment: we have 0 control on test/validation/production enviroment. We cannot install any other thing besides what we already have. So we really cannot run a node.js server.

Comment: Can you give more information about the back end then? Since that will determine what you can use. Support for IE5 (which doesn';t even support svg, hence the libs you tried failed in some way) has been dropped from basically every modern library, so your back end will need to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: I am using Struts 1 on Java 1.4, running on WebSphere Application Server 7.  Lightweight libraries are preferrable.

Comment: Does the app have to work on non-IE browsers? If not, you can try searching for an applet that creates pie charts, but they aren't supported anymore on different browsers. You will probably not be able to do this in javascript on IE5, since IE5 deosn't support SVG yet. So there's afaik no javascript library that can create graphics in IE5. Maybe you could create the pie in java, and have a struts Action send it back to the client.